# position a div on top of a video <object> in HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

im struggling how to position a `<div>` on top of a video `<object>`.

the blue border is my `<iframe>`. behind the video is my `<div class="title">some text</div>` that i wanted to be on top of the video and position it at the bottom right.

[image]

CSS and HTML

```
<style type="text/css">
.title {
    height:50px;
    width:150px; 
    border:1px solid #000;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
    background-color:pink;
    top:260px;left:0;
}
iframe {
    width:490px;
    height:400px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    border:2px solid blue;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="wrap" style="position:relative;">
    <div class="title">
        <h1>some text</h1>
    </div>

<iframe src="owlvid.html"></iframe>
</div>
</body>
```

this is the object inside my `owlvid.html`

```
<OBJECT classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921"
   codebase="http://downloads.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/latest/win32/axvlc.cab"
    width="480" height="300" id="vlc" events="True">

   <param name="Src" value="owl-vid-path-source" />
   <param name="ShowDisplay" value="True" />
   <param name="AutoLoop" value="False" />
   <param name="AutoPlay" value="True" />
   <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />

   <embed id="vlcEmb"  type="application/x-google-vlc-plugin" version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2" autoplay="yes" loop="no" width="480" height="300"
     target="owl-vid-path-source" ></embed>

</OBJECT>
```

Comment: It appears to work here... http://jsfiddle.net/uhRBN/

Comment: tried many times, but still wont work for me. im really not sure how yours work. :-/

Comment: i noticed that the iframe src is targeted to the youtube video. but i need to target an HTML page with the page in it.

Comment: I just used that as an example. If you provide the example you are using, I will take a look at it and figure it out!

Comment: I just answered a similar question, see here...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20440591/place-div-on-top-of-video-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
#wrap {
    position: absolute;
    width: 492px;
}
.title {
    background-color: #FFC0CB;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}
.title h1 {
    float: right;
    line-height: 1;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
}
iframe {
    border: 2px solid #0000FF;
    height: 400px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 490px;
}
</style>
<body>
  <div id="wrap">
    <div class="title">
      <h1>some text</h1>
    </div>
    <iframe src="owlvid.html"></iframe>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: i tried this but still didn't worked. any ideas why? the div is still behind the video `<object>`

Comment: @user1933824 Please see my latest revision and tell me if that's any closer to what you're looking for.

Comment: Maybe adding `z-index: 50;` to the element we want to be above the video should be enough.