# Place Div on top of video using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have several kinds of videos, like this

```
<video id='abd' height="200" width="200" ></video>

<embed id='bcd' height="200" width="200" ></embed>

<object id='cde' height="200" width="200" ></object>
```

I have calculated target position like this

```
<script>
    var vid=document.getElementById('abd');
    var width =  vid.offsetWidth;
    var height =  vid.height; 
    var x = width/2+ 'px';
    var y = height - 12+'px';

    var div = '<div>Heloo</div>';
</script>
```

Now i want to put a div at position (x,y).

How can i do this. div is stored in var div, Is there any way to do this perfectly,

Your help will be greatful

Thanks

Comment: would  be great if you can put some fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using pure CSS - no JS required!

**The HTML**

```
<div id="video-container">
    <iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>   </iframe>
    <div class="video-overlay">
        Overay Content
    </div>
</div>
```

**The CSS**

```
#video-container {
    position:relative;
    width:420px;
}
.video-overlay {
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    right:50px;
    background:#000;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

**See it in action**

http://jsfiddle.net/y28Zs/

Comment: but I want to do this in JS, because i will include file of JS on top of each page. and that JS file will place a div on each video. it will be a great thing

Comment: @user2341915 Sorry, but why would you use JS in favor of CSS if you don't have to? That's not a great thing, I guess.

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use JS to do this?

Comment: @EddSmith I want to put JS on my server, and in var div. I will store some sort of ads kind thing. And show that ad on all videos in pages. where my js included. Thats main idea to bring in reality. I dont want to have to put any div below or within another div on page, Just want to achieve this using JS. it will be a great invention, if we do this

Comment: In that case you could use CSS for the structure like demonstrated. But then on page load you could inject the image/HTML into the div using jQuery .html().

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

http://jsfiddle.net/miquelcamps/BJN8x/3/

**html**

```
<video id="embed" width="200" height="200" controls>
  <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

**javascript**

```
var vid    = document.getElementById('embed');
var width  = vid.width;
var height = vid.height;
var x      = vid.offsetLeft;
var y      = vid.offsetTop;

var div    = '<div class="overlay" style="height:'+height+'px;width:'+width+'px;left:'+x+'px;top:'+y+'px;">Hello</div>';

document.body.innerHTML += div;
```

**css**

```
.overlay{
    position:absolute;
    background:red;
    z-index:99;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check is it what you want :

```
<div id="adds">
<video id='abd' height="200" width="200" style="border:2px solid" ></video>
</div>
```

Javascript ----

```
vid=document.getElementById('abd');
addDiv =document.getElementById('adds');

var width =  vid.offsetWidth;
var height =  vid.height; 
var x = width/2+ 'px';
var y = height - 12+'px';


var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.innerText = "Hello....";
newDiv.style.left = "102px";
newDiv.style.top = "108px";
newDiv.style.position = "absolute";
addDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
```

Live demo : (http://jsfiddle.net/7EhtL/)